# Existence of a structure with the same properties as $\mathbb{N}$ and with an infinite element.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

So, we are requested to prove the existence a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ - first order logic - that has the same theory as the usual natural numbers and, moreover, there exists an element $\infty\in|\mathfrak{A}|$ such that it is "larger" than any other $x\in|\mathfrak{A}|$.

More specifically, let us consider a language $L$ with the only non-logical symbol being a binary predicate symbol $<$, a unary function symbol $S$ and a constant symbol $0$ and also let $\mathfrak{N}$ be the following structure:
$$\mathfrak{N}=\langle\mathbb{N};<^{\mathfrak{N}},S^{\mathfrak{N}},0^{\mathfrak{N}}\rangle$$
where $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, $<^{\mathfrak{N}}$ is the usual ordinance relation in the natural numbers, $S^{\mathfrak{N}}$ is the usual successor function and $0^{\mathfrak{N}}$ is the usual zero. Now, let us also consider the set of *sentences*:
$$\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}=\{\phi|\phi\text{ is a sentence and }{\mathfrak{N}}\models\phi\}$$
So, what we want now, is to show that there exists a structure $L$ in that language, let $\mathfrak{A}$:
$$\mathfrak{A}=\langle|\mathfrak{A}|;<^{\mathfrak{A}},S^{\mathfrak{A}},0^{\mathfrak{A}}\rangle$$
what has the property that there exists an element, let us note it with $\infty$, $\infty\in|\mathfrak{A}$ such that, for every $x\in\mathfrak{A}\setminus\{\infty\}$ we have that:
$$x<^{\mathfrak{A}}\infty$$
To prove this, we will use the Compactness Theorem (CT), as follows.

Let, for our own convenience note with $\mathbf{n}$ the terms:
$$\mathbf{n}:\underbrace{SS\dots S}_{n\text{ times}}0$$
for every $n=1,2,\dots$.

Let $\phi_n(x)$ be the following types:
$$\phi_n(x):\mathbf{n}<x$$
for every $n=1,2,\dots$.

Now, let also:
$$T=\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}\cup\{\phi_n(x):n=1,2,\dots\}$$
If $T'\subseteq T$ and $T'$ is finite, then there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$T'\subseteq\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}\cup\{\phi_n(x):n=1,2,\dots,k\}=\Sigma$$
For $\Sigma$, there exists a structure, $\mathfrak{N}$ itself, and a function $s:V\to|\mathfrak{N}|$ such that:
$$\mathfrak{N}\models \Sigma[s]$$
Indeed, if $s(x)=\mathbf{n+1}$, then it is clear that, using the definition of $\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}$ and the interpretation of $<^{\mathfrak{N}}$ and $S^{\mathfrak{N}}$.

So, we have also have that - since $T'\subseteq\Sigma$:
$$\mathfrak{N}\models T'[s]$$
and, as a result, since $T'$ was arbitrary, we have that $T$ is finitely satisfiable. Hence, from CT, we have that $T$ is also satisfiable, which means that there exists a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and a function $s:V\to|\mathfrak{A}|$ such that:
$$\mathfrak{A}\models T[s]$$
Let us note with $\infty$ the element:
$$\infty:=s(x)\in|\mathfrak{A}|$$
It is clear that, since $T$ is satisfiable, we have that:
$$x<^{\mathfrak{A}}\infty$$
for every $x\in|\mathfrak{A}|\setminus\{\infty\}$ and also that 
$$\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{A}=\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}$$
since, from the definition of $\mathfrak{A}$ we have that $\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}\subseteq\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{A}$ and, if $\phi$ was a sentence such that $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{A}\setminus\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}$ then, we would have that $\neg\phi\in\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}\subseteq\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{A}$ which is a contradiction.

So, we have proved the requested.

However, let us consider the following sentence:
$$\phi:\exists x\forall y(y<x)$$
It is clear that this is not true in $\mathbb{N}$, so $\phi\not\in\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}$, but it is true in $\mathfrak{A}$, so $\phi\in\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{A}=\mathrm{Th}\mathfrak{N}$.

Where's the mistake in all this?

I've thought of $<^{\mathfrak{A}}$ not being interpreted as a strict ordinance, but his is not the case, since the ordinance axioms can be described from sentences and they are modeled by $\mathfrak{N}$, so, by $\mathfrak{A}$, as well. Moreover, I cannot find any fault in the proof of the existence of $\mathfrak{A}$ using CT, however, I'm sure there should exist a mistake in all this.

Comment: If you use the compactness theorem then your sentence $\phi$ will not be true in the new model, either.

Comment: Yeap, I know, but from Tarski's defintion, we have that $\phi$ is true iff there exist $d\in|\mathfrak{A}|$ such that $\forall y(y<d)$ which is true if we choose $d=\infty$, as defined in structure $\mathfrak{A}$. That's why I'm  confused.

Comment: But $d=\infty$ will only be bigger than all the elements in the original structure, not all the elements of the new structure.  You might want to take a look at Skolem's model to get a clearer picture of what is going on.

Comment: Hmmm... So, since $\phi$ is not satisfied by $\mathfrak{A}$ we have that $$\forall x\exists y(\neg(y<x))$$, so there exists an element $y_{\infty}$ such that $\neg(y_{\infty}<\infty)$. So, from orinance axioms, we have that $$y_{\infty}=\infty\lor \infty<y_{\infty}$$. But, if $y_{\infty}=\infty$, then we come back to our initial case, so we should have that $\infty<y_{\infty}$. By induction we can find a sequence $y_\infty(n)$ such that $$\infty<y_\infty(1)<\dots<y_\infty(k)<y_\infty(k+1)<\dots$$ which implies that $|\mathfrak{A}|$ contains infinitely many "infinte" elements, right?

Comment: Certainly.  You might want to look up the structure of countable nonstandard models; see e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic#Structure_of_countable_non-standard_models).

Comment: So, my mistake was that I assumed that $\infty$ is a global maximum. However, how could one prove the original question and not what has been proved? The reason for asking this is that I found this as an old question in FOL exams so, I assume at least, it should be true. However, if this is true, then we have the abovementioned contradiction...

Comment: I assume that's a misprint.  Replace the last occurrence of $\mathfrak{A}$ by $\mathbb N$ and you get a correct statement.

Comment: Yeap, I see, this is the most obvious solution. So, there exists no such structure as the one requested, however there exists a structure as the one described by the proof - even I interpreted it in the wrong way, at first. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: "ordinance" does not mean what you think it does. You mean "order".

Comment: You must be right. Thank you for the clarification!